# arrows not scaled but grid does

Tags: tikz-arrows

I am trying to draw a arrow head in grid. but since it's too small, I add a scale to tikzpicture, then found the arrows actually not being scaled but grid does.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=10]
    \draw [step=.3mm,blue, very thin] (0,0) grid (3mm,3mm);
    \draw [-{Stealth[length=3mm, width=2mm]}] (0,1.5mm) -- (3mm,1.5mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you expect that will scale will scale arrows heads to? This is not a case. You should add scale to arrow head option too: `\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=10]
    \draw [step=.3mm,blue, very thin] (0,0) grid (3mm,3mm);
    \draw [-{Stealth[length=3mm, width=2mm, scale=10]}] (0,1.5mm) -- (3mm,1.5mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`